# Docker angular container - hot reload

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, nodemon

I have a dockerfile that builds my angular application:

```
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8 && npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 5004
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I want to add hot reloading to my docker container so that code changes automatically reflect in my browser.

**Nodemon** seems to be the best tool available to enable hot reloading, only I can't seem to configure it correctly with my Dockerfile.

Can someone explain to me the best method of using nodemon in Docker so that my angular app can hot reload?

Comment: If you're actually editing the files in the container, `ng serve` already *does* hot reloading.

Comment: Inside my src/app folder is a folder called 'home' that contains a 'home.component.html' file. Changing the contents of that folder while the container is running, and then refreshing the page, the changes do not reflect until i rebuild the container with the same image/dockerfile

Comment: Right, because you're copying the files into the container; they're not the same files. Nodemon won't help with that.

Comment: Ah okay. So I would need to use a volume with my container to add the actual files into the container?

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile copies all the project data into the container. These copies will be uneffected by file changes on your host machine.

To change this you can mount a volume with your project code into the container. To do so run your container with this:

```
-v ./src:/usr/src/app/src
```

It will mount your local angular src folder into the container. Without overwriting your installed npm_modules folder.

If you're on windows there is a problem with hyper-v and file changes. As a workaround you can run ng serve with the --poll flag to enable polling. In our file it would be

```
CMD ng serve --poll 200 --host 0.0.0.0
```

ng serve will now actively check for file changes every 200 ms.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled host check by `--disable-host-check` flag. This [Docker Angular Hot-Reload Template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-angular) should help.